How to regularly transfer changes in Git from one branch to another?
I want to work in a branch A and from time to time drop changes from A to a branch B.\
But I don't want to close or delete the branch A, I want to keep working in it.
What is the best way to do this? 
I mean, I want to find the right approach so that I can do it regularly, without any extra tweaks.
Cherry-pick? Merge with some options? Something else?
Or is it considered a bad practice at all?
If I use "git merge" A into B, it literally gets merged into B. But I don't want it, I only want to transfer accumulated changes to B, and work in A further.
I know that "git merge" doesn't close or delete the merged branch. But is it a good practice to re-use a branch after merging it?

merge doesn't delete a branch and merging does exactly what you want: it brings integrates changes of one branch into another branch. You have to clarify why you think that merge does not work for your use case.

I know that "git merge" doesn't close or delete the merged branch. But is it a good practice to re-use a branch after merging it? That's basically my question.

Git can handle it just fine, so I don't see why not. But Git lets you choose your workflow, cherry-pick, rebase, merge – whatever works best for you

If A's changes don't depend on B, I'd just rebase B on top of A every time you need to get those changes:
(branch_b)$ git rebase branch_a

